# While using .env file in mongodb then it shows me error

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I have installed dotenv while creating the mongodb file. then i got my user and password. to secure that i used .env file like

```
"${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASS}"
```

then it is showing me bad auth. along with that it is showing codeName:

```
'AtlasError',
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'HandshakeError' } this.
```

Comment: What's the `console.log(\`"${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASS}"\`)` say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you have used `""` for the encapsulation and `${}` (template literals):

```js
"${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASS}"
```

You have to use backticks like below to make this work and not double quotes:

```js
`${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASS}`
```

This one's a common problem that's been done by new folks working with JavaScript's new features.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am actually a newcomer!

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that too. Now I have accepted your answer.